# Powershell Remove-Item on folder failing only when run through Ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I have a powershell function that completely deletes a directory. I've built it as per recommended for powershell as so (with some extra tracing in there)

```
function DeleteFolderAndContents()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string] $folder_path
    )

    Get-ChildItem -Path "$folder_path" -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
    Write-Host "Deleted all files in directory. Will attempt to delete directory next"  
    Start-Sleep 3
    Write-Host "Slept for 3 seconds. Now trying to remove folder"   
    Remove-Item "$folder_path" -Force 
    Write-Host "DeleteFolderAndContents worked seemingly without error"     
    while (Test-Path "$folder_path") { Start-Sleep 10 } 
}
```

If I run it through the Powershell cmdline it works no problem. When Ansible tries to run the same script (through the Script task), the Get-ChildItem part works, deleting all folder contents, but the Remove-Item fails to completely eliminate the directory.

I get the following error message

```
System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: 
An object at the specified path C:\\bblabla\\blabla\\blabla\\A.C.S.Api  does not exist.
              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeThePath(String basepath, Stack`1 tokenizedPathStack), 
            at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeRelativePathHelper(String path, String basePath)
```

I have no idea why this would happen. I'm pretty sure its an Ansible issue but don't understand how that could be and I don't know what to do about it

Comment: you got it @techraf

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. There was a hidden trailing space at the end of the path because of my Ansible implementation. For some reason, PowerShell ignored the space in the Get-ChildItem call but not in the Remove-Item call.